# Was operation "Wandering Soul" any bit successful?

Tags: vietnam-war

For anyone who doesn't know,

> Operation Wandering Soul was a propaganda campaign and large-scale
> psychological warfare attempt exercised by U.S. forces during the
> Vietnam War. U.S. Forces hoped that the operation would weaken the
> morale of the Viet Cong and prey on the fears of many Vietnamese.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Wandering_Soul_(Vietnam_War)))

Listening to the audiotapes, it sure did give me the creeps, but I doubt it would scare anyone who wasn't superstitious. I imagine that it wouldn't scare the Viet Cong from fighting, especially since they probably have seen and heard more disturbing things in the war itself. U.S Troops would have to play the audio near the enemy so that they could hear it, which means they would have to know where the enemy was, and in that case why not call in an airstrike? Also, the Viet Cong eventually figured out that the sounds were from speakers, and would just fire in that direction.

I love the idea of psychological warfare, but in the end, I just think this was a really ineffective attempt at weakening the morale of the Viet Cong, so why did this operation even happen in the first place?

Comment: Your opening sentence has been copied verbatim from the Wikipedia article [Operation Wandering Soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Wandering_Soul_(Vietnam_War)). Please attribute properly to avoid plagiarism. Thank you.

Comment: Made the quote a proper blockquote (using the little tool in the editor that looks like a quotation mark). My SWAG about the CIA is that if you have heard about one of their PsyOps publicly, that's probably because it wasn't very effective.